# What function do the resistors and capacitors serve in this 1:1 audio isolation circuit

Tags: audio, isolation

I want to better understand this circuit, which essentially just puts a +/- audio channel through a 1:1 audio isolation transformer. I am having trouble understanding what the resistors to ground, as well as the RC between the output +/- do. Any resources on the subject would appreciated.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 20k resistors could be just pull-down resistors to prevent the inputs/outputs to be left floating (i.e. to prevent noise pick-up) when nothing is connected.

As for the RC pair at the output, it's a Zobel network to prevent self-resonance effects.

Answer (score 0):

The 20k resistors to ground prevent a large charge from building up on the audio line that create a “pop!” when you plug the cable and cause a discharge.

The series RC circuit shunts frequencies above the audio range (20kHz) to  ground.